# How can I center UICollectionViewFlowLayout with two columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView where I want this:

```
[    x    x    ]
[    x    x    ]
```

Each UICollectionViewCell is `120x120` using:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(120, 120);
}
```

I cannot figure out how to make the two columns center. With the same amount in the left, middle and right.

Can you help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you prepared to write a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sectionInset` to dictate the margins. Use `minimumInteritemSpacing` to determine the space between the items.

Comment: Those are the limits of the customizability of the built-in UICollectionViewFlowLayout. As I've indicated in my comment above, what you really want to do is subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout.