# How can I center Buttons within UICollectionViewFlowLayout for two columns? Might there be a more efficient way to solve this?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout, uiedgeinsets

I am implementing a menu, which holds severals buttons within two columns and I want the button text to be centered in the middle for every cell.

---

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

This is my code for `ViewController`:

```swift
import SideMenu
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var button_titles : [String] = ["Action", "KnowHow", "Beginner", "Expert", "Level Up", "What is", "How to use", "Home"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Prana Power"
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ButtonCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ButtonMainMenu")
    }
      
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         //collection.reloadData()
     }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let flowayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let space: CGFloat = (flowayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.left ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.right ?? 0.0)
        let size:CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.size.width - space) / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }
    

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return button_titles.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ButtonMainMenu", for: indexPath) as? ButtonCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}
        cell.btnClick.setTitle(button_titles[indexPath.item], for: .normal)
        cell.btnClick.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 20)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return cell
    }
    
    
    }
```

So the button is centered within in my storyboard for `ButtonCollectionViewCell` as one can see in the `debug view hierarchy`, but not within the outer cell:

[image]

I have set the insets for collection view like:

[image]

I tried to use the second answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267662/how-to-center-horizontally-uicollectionview-cells)
as solution:

```swift
func centerItemsInCollectionView(cellWidth: Double, numberOfItems: Double, spaceBetweenCell: Double, collectionView: UICollectionView) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let totalWidth = cellWidth * numberOfItems
    let totalSpacingWidth = spaceBetweenCell * (numberOfItems - 1)
    let leftInset = (collectionView.frame.width - CGFloat(totalWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2
    let rightInset = leftInset
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftInset, bottom: 0, right: rightInset)
}
```

When I run the code afterwards it seems to have no effect on my view.
I tried to alter the function to

```swift
    func centerItemsInCollectionView(cellWidth: Double, numberOfItems: Double, spaceBetweenCell: Double, collectionView: UICollectionView) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
    }
```

to check if it has any effects at all, but after relaunching the app everything is the same.

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572042/how-can-i-center-uicollectionviewflowlayout-with-two-columns) I got the hint, that I might have to set `minimumInteritemSpacing`. I tried to set `flowayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing = 6` within my collectionView function for returning `CGSize` without any effect.

---

So my two questions are:

1. Is there any easier way to achieve my desired layout? Since I am rather knew to iOS and swift I am not that familiar with all the possibilities to create layouts.
2. How can I fix my Problem within the current code?

Please let me now, if you have any tips, solutions or insights on this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using storyboard autoloayout?

Comment: you set here `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` but you set estimated size `.automatic` just change it to `.none` it will work :).

Comment: @Kudos how would you be using autolayout for this matter?

Comment: @RB's I tried to change this but had no effect on relaunch sadly

Comment: Autolayout fixed it now, I had some conflicting constraints! thanks!

Comment: @FelixOuttaSpace Was I right??

Comment: @kudos yes it fixed the problem setting the distance to the cell. I tried to set this before but had to try a little bit more, now it works thanks!

Comment: I am providing answer Pease mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **storyboard Autoloayout**.
You surely have **constraints conflictions**.

```
     |
-  Button -
     |
```